# How should i go with the program flow in cakephp?(MVC)

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm getting my feet wet with cakephp and i am starting getting used to the concepts.
I want to know what would be the best way to do this using the MVC flow.

Lets say this is my default.ctp layout:

```
<body>
<div id="container"><?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?></div>
<div id="tagcloud"></div>
</body>
```

My controller is Posts where when i call index() action it will list all the posts on the database.

I also have a controller Tags which access a table with how much times each tag was used to tag a post.

What i need is to generate a tagcloud that should be in any page. So, where should i write my tagcloud code?

My first tought was to obviously write it in the Tags controller, but how will i output the tagcloud to the layout?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [Components](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html):

> Components are packages of logic that are shared between controllers. If you find yourself wanting to copy and paste things between controllers, you might consider wrapping some functionality in a component.

In that case you should import the models to use in the component.

Answer (score 1):

In your PostsController::index() you could do this:

```
public function index() {

    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate()); // pass a paginated list of posts to the view

    $this->set('tagCloud', $this->Post->tag->tagcloud()); // pass the tag cloud data to the view

}
```

In your Tag Model:

```
public function tagcloud() {

    $tagcloud = //funky code to build a tagcloud

    return $tagcloud;

}
```

Alternatively, you could package up your tag cloud into an element:

/app/View/Elements/tagcloud.ctp:

```
<?php

$tagCloud = $this->requestAction('/tags/tagcloud');

// code to display your tag cloud in the Tag Model as before.

?>
```

and insert into into your index.ctp for Posts with:

```
<?php echo $this->Element('tagcloud'); ?>
```

and in your TagsController:

```
public function tagcloud() {

   return $this->tagcloud();

}
```

and put the logic for building your tagcloud in the Tag model as before.